# How to only map an Array once in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am mapping an array that comes from an API call into a div. This mapping runs a function for each item of the array, to know where to position it on a CSS Grid.

However, every time that I click on one of these items to expand it (and I do the expanding via setState), I believe the mapping runs again and, therefore, so does the function to position the items on the CSS Grid. Needless to say, this messes up the whole item positioning, every time I click to expand one of them.

How can I make sure that the mapping happens only once, when the page renders, and not every time I click (setState) on one of the items?

Here's the render code:

```js
const firstColumnLength = 5;
const secondColumnLength = 10;

var endLeftRowOn = 1;
var endRightRowOn = 1;

let heightsLeft = [1];
let heightsRight = [1];

var startRightRowOn = 0;
var startLeftRowOn = 0;

const getEndRow = (i,w,h) => {
  const imgSize = [w, h];
  const ratio = Math.round((imgSize[1] / imgSize[0])*100)/100;

  /* Right side column */

  if(i & 1) {
  let rightImageHeight = Math.round(4 * ratio);

  endRightRowOn = endRightRowOn + rightImageHeight;

  heightsRight.push(endRightRowOn);

  startRightRowOn = heightsRight[heightsRight.length - 1] + endRightRowOn;

  return endRightRowOn
  } else {
    let startLeftRowOn = heightsLeft[heightsLeft.length - 1];

    let leftImageHeight = Math.round(5 * ratio);

    endLeftRowOn = endLeftRowOn + leftImageHeight;

    heightsLeft.push(endLeftRowOn);

    startLeftRowOn = heightsLeft[heightsLeft.length - 1];

    return endLeftRowOn
  }
};

render() {
  return(
    <div class="gallery-world">
      <GalleryGrid numberOfRows={24}>
        {this.state.artList.map((e,i) => (e.sys.contentType.sys.id === "art" ?
          <ArtDiv startColumn={i & 1 ? firstColumnLength : 1}
            endColumn={i & 1 ? 10 : firstColumnLength}
            startRow={i & 1 ? endRightRowOn : endLeftRowOn}
            endRow={getEndRow(i,(e.fields.image.fields.file.details.image.width),(e.fields.image.fields.file.details.image.height))}
            className="artImage"
            id={"artImage-" + (i)}
            style={{backgroundImage: `url(${e.fields.image.fields.file.url})`}}
            onClick={() => this.openItem(e.fields.image.fields.file.url)}
          ></ArtDiv>
          : 
          "")
        )}
      </GalleryGrid>
      <OpenArt
        imageToOpen={this.state.imageIs}
        displayArt={this.state.openImage}
        closeItem={() => this.closeItem()}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try creating a problematic sample on Codesandbox.

Comment: Can you please provide the method `this.openItem`?

Comment: Update the state in useEffect(), so it will only run the effect if anything in the dependency array changes or if the dependency array is empty, then it runs it once.

Comment: @dns_nx updated the original post. It's a bit of a monster tbh, still learning

Comment: You should provide your component code, or at least your state update functions.